# Is there a mental disorder that causes people to do things in their sleep?

Tags: sleep, mental-health, sleep-walking

As the title says, what can cause high amounts of activity during one's sleep? Activity like: switching on lights, and walking around outside.

Comment: Consult a physician.

Comment: Please review the guidelines for asking questions - under Help on the website. (I don't know if the Help menu is accessible using the app - I cannot find it on the iOS app.)

Comment: @MarkDWorthenPsyD I had a look at the "don't ask" section and found this `However, if your motivation is “I would like others to explain ______ to me”, then you are probably OK.` which I think applies. Is there a specific part of the guideline that you would like me to see? I'm fairly new to this stack exchange.

Comment: Your final paragraph basically asks us what you should do, and that's what we can't answer. When people get out of bed and do things in their sleep, that's sleep walking. It sounds like that's what you're doing, but we have no way of knowing for sure. You need to consult a physician.

Comment: There are sleep disorders that can cause this type of unconscious behavior, but there is no way anyone can determine the presence or nature of any sleep disorders you might have over the Internet. **You need to see a sleep medicine physician.**

Comment: With regard to the guidelines for asking questions, it is confusing since they are not all located in one place. The relevant one for your question is under [What topics can I ask about here?](https://health.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) - "If your question is requesting personal medical advice, it is off-topic and instead should be directed to your personal physician."

Comment: Ok. Other than consult a physician, what should I do about this question? Can I rephrase it to be less personal or do I need to delete it?

Comment: If you edit it to remove all the personal details and the request for advice and simply ask the question contained in the title, it would be an acceptable question.

Comment: Once you strip out the personal details, it's definitely an answerable question, but it brings up another of SE policies: trying to answer your own question before bringing it to the site.  Share the sources of what you've learned so far in your search for the answer.  The question as it is posed right now makes it seem like you didn't even google it - you would have at least run into disorders like sleep walking with a simple google search.

Comment: I'm not sure why the question got closed _after_ you edited it but I have nominated it for reopening. It will take a few more votes to actually reopen.

Answer (score -3):

you`d better find a partner to live with, it is dangerous to be lonely today, many mental disorders have sleep troubles, PTSD is common, anxiety is not a disease if controlled

Comment: Welcome to Health.SE. Since health is an important topic, the site has a strict policy that all answers should be [backed up with reliable references](https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/should-we-require-references-to-back-up-all-answers), in order to provide the community with the means to assess the merit of the answer, regardless of the reader's background. *See [this list of reliable sources](https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112/what-are-reliable-sources)*. If you still have trouble with this, feel free to visit the [help].